# select coordinate data by radius from a given point

Tags: r

I have data with x,y coordinates for which I would like to make a selection based on a radius from a given point. So far, my search only yielded solutions more targeted towards geographical data and I wanted to know if there's a generic, non-geo way to do this.

**Sample data:**

```
set.seed(00) 
dt = data.table("group" = rep(1:2, times=2, each=50),"xloc" = runif(100, min=-1, max=1),"yloc" = runif(100, min=-1, max=1))
```

**A square attempt:**

For the example data, I would like a circular enclosure of `0.5` radius, starting from `[0,0]`. But my attempt has only taken me as far as a square enclosure:

```
dt$position = "out"
dt$position[dt$xloc >-0.5 & dt$xloc <0.5 & dt$yloc >-0.5 & dt$yloc <0.5] = "in"
```

... which looks like this with the obvious spillage.

```
ggplot(dt, aes(xloc, yloc))+geom_point(aes(colour=factor(position)))+
  annotate("path",
           x=0+.5*cos(seq(0,2*pi,length.out=100)),
           y=0+.5*sin(seq(0,2*pi,length.out=100)))+facet_grid(~group)
```

[image]

What is a more accurate and preferably efficient way of doing this? A method that can accomodate multiple nested grouping variables.

Please and thank you in advance.

Comment: Pythagoras is your friend...;-)

Comment: I suspect, but my knowledge of both the maths and programming is so abysmal I have to seek help here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing the second chunk of your code shown here to this should work:

```
dt$position = "out"
dt$position[(dt$xloc)^2 + (dt$yloc)^2 <0.5] = "in"
```

Comment: oh yes! thank you! but it should be `<0.25` instead of 0.5